# how to get & use return value in google scripts

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-apps-script

I have a function in Google Scripts in funcs.gs that is returning an object.
Depending on what the user inputs the object returns and displays some results. But I would like to take it a step further and use those results to dictate if an error message would show up. I'm out of ideas hence my reasoning for asking here.

```
function data(num){

   
 if (condition met){
    
    let Obj = {thing1:value1, thing2: value2}
    return prjObj;
    
    //Obj works perfectly fine 
    
}else{
     
   let Obj = {thing1: value3, thing2: value4};

  return  Obj;
  //this also works fine 
  
}//end of if statement  
}//end of getData function
```

now I use a function (jQuery used but not needed) in the HTML file

```
$(function redbox(){
let repeater = setTimeout(redbox, 5000);

let redbox1 ={}
redbox1.hidebox = document.getElementById("something").hidden = true;
redbox1.unhidebox = document.getElementById("something").hidden = false;

//i tried this and just tried to put redbox1.unhidebox under the return statement but it does not work 
//google.script.run.Data(redbox1 )

console.log(google.script.run.data());
})
```

I'm not sure why the data function is returning undefined even when I use num as a parameter.
The goal is to set the hidden element to false when the else statement is invoked. I used the rexbox1 as an object because that would allow me to pass it as a parameter in the data function, but it's not displayed.

Comment: Data and data are not the same function capitalization counts.

Comment: Ya I didn’t write it properly but they both the same in the actual code, I edited it now though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [google.script.run.myFunction()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myfunction...-any-server-side-function) will return `void` as described in the documentation:

> this method is asynchronous and does not return directly; however, the server-side function **can return** a value to the client as a parameter **passed to a success handler**

Therefore, to retrieve what your function is returning you must use it along with the method [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) like this:

```js
function redbox(returnedValue) {
  console.log(returnedValue);
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(redbox).data(num);
```

The value returned from your Apps Script function will be passed to your desired function in the HTML JavaScript script if there are no errors on your Apps Script function.

Answer (score 2):

Just try writing it like this:

Get rid of all that other junk.

javascript:

```
function getData() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){
    console.log(obj.foo);
  })
  .data()
}
```

gs:

```
function data() {
  return {foo:bar}
}
```